# Code Explanation (fs) from Sequelize Express Example

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, fs

I'm currently learning Sequelize with Node/Express, and am taking a look at the example posted here: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example

I want a full picture of how this works, and what it's doing, but I've never worked with fs before and am having trouble puzzling out what this snippet of code does, from index.js:

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that the variable db is an instance of Sequelize. Anybody that can explain this to me? The rest of it makes sense, but I just can't puzzle this piece out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first call to [`readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path) gets all the files in the directory of the currently executing script in a synchronous fashion (in this case `/models/index.js` is the currently executing script, so [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) points to the `models` directory). The files in this directory are `['index.js', 'task.js', 'user.js']`.

```
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
```

The below function call filters out the files that start with a `.` or are named `index.js`
So after this function call, the list of files should be `['task.js', 'user.js']`.

```
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
```

Iterates over each file name and imports the file into the db.

```
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
```

Iterates over each model in the db (Task and User) and invokes its associate function (if it has one), presumably to setup any associations between models, foreign keys, cascades, etc.

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

This seems like a fairly useful idiom, as it allows you to keep model definitions like tasks and users in separate files, and it would prevent you from having to load up each model individually with separate lines of code (of which there could be many). Doing it this way would allow you to continue adding new models without potentially forgetting to add the code to load it up in your index.js file.

[Documentation for `fs` (File System).](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: Thanks man!! Very helpful, it is indeed a useful snippet - I'll be sure to include this in my project.

Comment: Now association has been changed, please update the answer!!